# error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, user-interface

i'm getting this error 
./CreatePanel.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    redText=new Jlabel();
                ^
  symbol:   class Jlabel
  location: class CreatePanel
how do I fix this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CreatePanel extends JPanel
 {
   private Vector petList; 
   private JButton button1;
   private SelectPanel sPanel;
   private JLabel text1;
   private Jlabel redText;
   private JTextField petInput;
   private JTextArea petsIn;
   private Panel wPanel;
   private Panel alertPanel;
   private Panel petPanel;
   private Panel createPanel;



 public CreatePanel(Vector petList, SelectPanel sPanel)
  {
    this.petList = petList;
    this.sPanel = sPanel;


    // orgranize components here
    // here is an example
    text1=new JLabel("Enter a Pet Type"); 

    redText=new Jlabel();

    petInput=new JTextField();

    button1=new JButton("Create a Pet");

    petsIn=new JTextArea("No Pet");

    wPanel=new Panel(); 

    petPanel=new Panel();  

    createPanel=new Panel(); 

    alertPanel=new Panel();

    alertPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    createPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));

    petPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    wPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));  

    button1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    add(wPanel);

    wPanel.add(alertPanel);

    alertPanel.add(redText);

    wPanel.add(petPanel);

    petPanel.add(text1);

    petPanel.add(petInput);

    wPanel.add(createPanel);

    createPanel.add(new JLabel());

    createPanel.add(button1);

    createPanel.add(new JLabel());  

    createPanel.add(new JLabel());  

    createPanel.add(new JLabel());

    createPanel.add(new JLabel());

    add(petsIn);

  }

  private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
         //when the button is pushed, the pet type
         //should be added to the list. This is also where
         //errors are handled.
         String inputPet = petInput.getText(); 

         boolean checker = false; 

         for (int p = 0; p < petList.size(); p++){ 
             if (inputPet.equalsIgnoreCase((String) petList.get(p))){
                checker = true; 

                 break;
             }
         }


         if(inputPet.equals("")){
             redText.setText("Please enter a pet type.");

             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
         } 
         else if (checker == true){
             redText.setText("The pet type already exists.");

             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
         }
          else {
             petList.add(inputPet);

             String addedPets = (String) petList.get(0);

             for(int i = 1; i < petList.size(); i++){
                 addedPets += "\n" + (String) petList.get(i);
             }
             redText.setText("Pet type added.");
             redText.setForeground(Color.red);
             petsIn.setText(addedPets);
             sPanel.updateUI();             
          } 
     } //end of actionPerformed method
         redText.setText("");

  } //end of ButtonListener class

} //end of CreatePanel class
```

i'm getting this error 
./CreatePanel.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    redText=new Jlabel();
                ^
  symbol:   class Jlabel
  location: class CreatePanel
how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your declaration of JLabel for redText is "Jlabel" when it should be "JLabel".  Need an uppercase L.

Comment: I am now getting this error ./CreatePanel.java:139: error: <identifier> expected
         redText.setText("");
                        ^
./CreatePanel.java:139: error: illegal start of type
         redText.setText("");
                         ^
./CreatePanel.java:139: error: package redText does not exist
         redText.setText("");
                ^

Comment: I believe the "} //end of actionPerformed method redText.setText("");" is your culprit there.  It's outside of your actionPerformed method.  I'm guessing you probably don't want that extra "redText.setText("");" so it'd be safe to remove it.